# Securing a multi-user permission structure

Tags: security, installation, permissions, filesystem

I'm currently working on a team that needs two distinct users from the same `wpadmin` group to be able to modify the wordpress files.

Following the guide at [Hardening WordPress (Codex)](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/), the following commands would give `755` and `644` access to directories and files respectively:

```
find /path/to/my/wordpress/install/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /path/to/my/wordpress/install/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

But the lack of the `g+w` permission would make this unusable on a multi-user environment.

What best practices should I follow in this case? Is it secure to just do

```
find /path/to/my/wordpress/install/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find /path/to/my/wordpress/install/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

To add group access?